# cant get dropdownlist inside panel

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function Validate() {
        var fromFolder = document.GetElementById('<%= pnSearch.FindControl("ddlFromFolders").ClientID %>');//.value;

        alert(fromFolder);
    }
</script>
<asp:Panel ID="pnSearch" runat="server" GroupingText="Search Positions for move historic PnL" DefaultButton="btnMove" Width="550">
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFromFolders" Width="150" runat="server" DataTextField="ShortName" DataValueField="Id" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
        <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="Choose folder" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <div align="right">
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Move PnL" ID="btnMove" OnClick="btnMove_OnClick" OnClientClick="Validate();" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Can someone please help me with this? Tying to get the selected value from the dropdownlist but I can't figure it out..

Comment: `GetElementById() != getElementById()`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no problem directly accessing the drop down by id cause. it is not inside template. So:

```
var fromFolder = document.getElementById('<%= ddlFromFolders.ClientID %>').value;
```

And you had a typo in `getElementById`, as pointed out in comments